# Devc++ al compilar y seleccionar una opcion deja de funcionar

Tags: c++, c, dev-c++

estoy empezando a aprender el lenguaje C, entonces en un ejercicio me pide hacer un menú que considere las siguientes opciones

caso 1: Cubo de un numero
caso 2: Saber si el numero es par o impar
caso 3: salir del programa

al compilar todo bien, pero cuando voy a colocar una opción el programa deja de funcionar aqui abajo les dejare el código:

```
 #include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int num1,opcion;
    printf("Digite un numero: ");
    scanf("%i", &num1);
    printf("\nOpcion 1: Obtener el cubo de ese numero");
    printf("\nOpcion 2: Saber si el numero es par o impar");
    printf("\nOpcion 3: Salir del programa");
    printf("\nDiga la opcion que desea realizar con el numero: ");
    scanf("%i", opcion);
    switch(opcion) {
        case 1: 
        num1 = pow(num1,3);
        printf("El cubo del numero dado es: %i", num1);
        break;
        case 2: 
        if(num1 % 2 == 0) {
            printf("El numero es par :D");
        }
            else {
                printf("El numero es impar :*D");
            }
            break;
        
        case 3: 
        printf("Ha salido del programa con exito");
        break;
        default: printf("Ha dado una opcion incorrecta, cerrando el programa");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y pega el código, no lo subas como imagen

Comment: Listo :D, ya lo coloque como texto

Answer (score 2):

Bueno se te pasó por alto un pequeño detalle.
Tu variable `opcion` va guardar un valor, entonces cambia la siguiente línea de código

```
scanf("%i", opcion); //esto está mal
scanf("%i", &opcion); //así es como debería ser
```

Cuando vas asignar un valor tienes que referenciar a que variable va ir asignado como lo hiciste en tu variable `num1`, no confundas cuando muestras el mensaje con una variable que ya tiene asignado un valor

```
printf("El cubo del numero dado es: %i", num1); //esto está bien porque num1 ya tiene un valor asignado
```

Comment: Ahh si ya vi el error, muchas gracias no lo había pillado jajajajaja